# How to send mail when new blog post is published to subscribed users in django?

Tags: django

**How to send mail when new post is published to subscribed users in django**

Comment: The current question is too broad. How do you represent "subscribed users", what view are you currently using to publish a blogpost, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provide a couple of wrapper to send email very easily, please have a look a the [official documentation for sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/)

For example if you wanted to send mail after a given instruction :

```
 from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to a field where your subscribers will be placed.

```
    subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed', blank=True)
```

You can create a signal in blog post view like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def send_mail_to_subs(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for subs in instance.author.subscribed.all():
            send_mail(
                f'New Post from {instance.author}',
                f'Title: {instance.post_title}',
                'youremail',
                [subs.email],
            )
```

Good coding :)